# Integrate Twice over Symbolic Interval

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I would like to solve:

$$
\int _0^1\int _y^11dxdy
$$

In one function call to Integrate[]. However, evaulating

```
Integrate[1, {x, y, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]  (*1-y*)
```

Gives the wrong answer, while splitting it up like

```
temp = Integrate[1, {x, y, 1}]      (*1-y*)
Integrate[temp, {y, 0, 1}]          (*1/2*)
```

outputs the correct answer.

Comment: Just swap the order of your integration regions `Integrate[1, {y, 0, 1}, {x, y, 1}]`

Comment: That fixes the problem. Thanks!

Comment: See "Details and Options" section of help page on `Integrate`: "The first variable given corresponds to the outermost integral and is done last."

Comment: "The first variable ... is done last." Why does Mathematica choose such a confusing notation for the `Integrate[]` method ?

Comment: @asmaier It was definitely "backwards" to how I understood it initially. It should be left-to-right, right?? But it is left-to-right if you look at the symbolic integrals. The outermost integral is always the most left integral, so thinking about it that way has helped me.